# GET Body is not being sent with APIClient Django DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, http, django-rest-framework, get

i want to send body data using get request in the django drf test case `APITestCase`

for example

```
data ={'hi':'bye'}
self.client.get('media_list/', {'body': data})
```

and in the views i can able get the body using below code

```
request.data.get('hi', None)
```

but it is not working using `{'body': data}` my test method but it is working fine in the `postman` raw type.

what is tried is(not working)

```
self.client.get('media_list/', data=data)
```

Comment: GET requests do not include any body.  If you want data sent, either add it to query params, or change the request to a POST

Comment: @json ok, now a days we can able to send body in get request right?

Comment: no.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET, and the section `request has body`

Answer (score 13):

I faced this issue while writing unit test. You can solve it with this workaround.

***Problem***: When you request with client.get method, the method put your data to url. You can see link in the below.
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/test.py#L194

***Solution***: You should use `client.generic()` directly. Don't use `client.get()` https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/test.py#L203

Example

```py
import json
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class TestClass(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Setup run before every test method.
        pass

    def test_send_json_in_body(self):
        data ={'hi' : 'bye'}
        resp = self.client.generic(method="GET", path="/return/data/", data=json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

```sh
request._request
<WSGIRequest: GET '/return/data/'>
request.data
{'hi': 'bye'}
```

It works  :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Works great. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

data` returns request body and for get api's you need to get query params
Try bellow code:

```py
data = {'hi':'bye'}
self.client.get('media_list/', data)


request.query_params.get('hi', None)
```